# Регулярное выражение Python для одиночного "-"

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, python-3.5

У меня есть следующее регулярное выражение в python:

```
pattern1 = re.compile('[a-zA-z]{1}[a-z-A-z0-9]*["."][a-z-A-z0-9]*\-[a-z-A-z0-9]*$')
```

Как я могу заставить его соответствовать только одному знаку минус? Как `abc123.abc123-abc123`, но не `abc123.abc123----abc123`.

Метод, который я использую, кажется, работает с точкой, но не с минусом.

Comment: Так удалите вы эти дефисы из символьных классов. `["."]` надо заменить на ``\.``

Comment: Не надо использовать регулярные выражения там, где всё можно решить простейшим парсером.

Answer (score 3):

Вы вероятно хотите это регулярное выражение:

```
[a-zA-z][a-zA-z0-9]*\.[a-zA-z0-9]+-[a-zA-z0-9]+$
```

---

Разбор:

```
[a-zA-z]
```

Первое совпадение на английской букве (`a-z` строчные, `A-Z` прописные).

---

```
[a-zA-z0-9]*
```

Затем может быть любое количество (`*` значит от `0` до бесконечна) английских букв (`a-zA-Z`) или цифр (`0-9`)

---

```
\.
```

Затем нужна быть *точка* (буквально).

---

```
[a-zA-z0-9]+
```

Затем опять любое количество английских букв или цифр, но теперь *по крайней мере один* из этих знаков (`+` значит от `1` до бесконечна).

---

```
-
```

Буквально этот знак минус (`-`)

---

```
[a-zA-z0-9]+
```

Это уже знаем (смотри выше).

---

```
$
```

Затем уже *не может быть ничего другого* (`$` значит конец строки).

---

Примечания:

1. Вы тоже можете хотеть начинать с начала строки:

   `^[a-zA-z][a-zA-z0-9]*\.[a-zA-z0-9]+-[a-zA-z0-9]+$`

   (`^` значит c начала).
2. Безопаснее применить `r` перед регулярным выражением:

   `pattern1 = re.compile(r'[a-zA-z][a-zA-z0-9]*\.[a-zA-z0-9]+-[a-zA-z0-9]+$')`

Comment: Точка означает любой симво. Вероятно, ты имел в виду `\.`.

Comment: @Qwertiy спацибо, я поправил мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто убрать дефисы)) Если не получиться то как сказал Wiktor Stribizew заменить \ 
Все просто

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ["."]
> ```

Это что-то не то.

> ```
> [a-z-A-z0-9]
> ```

```
[a-zA-z0-9]
```